# python logging - not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

When I try to print an exception to my logger object, it throws the following exception

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What would be the right format to handle these errors?

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    a = 0 /0
except Exception, e:
    logger.error("message received", e)
    print 'over'
```

Comment: `logging` uses string formatting to format the first string with subsequent arguments. I think you mean something like `logger.error("message received: %s", e)`

Comment: For this specific scenario, it's better to use `logger.exception("msg")`, which automatically includes the traceback after the message.